# Printing Jquery Bracket in JSPDF using Angular2

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, jspdf

I am using Jquery Bracket for generating bracket for sports application.

[Jquery Bracket Plugin](http://aropupu.fi/bracket/)

I have used the following code to generate bracket,

```
 var mData = {
    teams : [
      ["John Anderson", "Peter Robert"], /* first matchup */
      ["Maria Lucos", "Usha Elizabeth"]  /* second matchup */
    ],
    results : [
      [[1,2], [3,4]],       /* first round */
      [[4,6], [2,1]]        /* second round */
    ]
  }


    $(function() {
        $('.demo').bracket({
          init: mData /* data to initialize the bracket with */ })
      })
```

Now we have a div with class demo in html.In this we will append n number of bracketing data. We want to convert this html data into pdf. For that we have used the following code in jspdf,

```
print_brackets(){
     var pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'letter', true);
         pdf.internal.scaleFactor =3.5;
  recursivePDF(0,1,splitTitle);
function recursivePDF(i,n,splitTitle) {

var checkholdin =0;
    if(i == 0){
        var k =100
        var l=80
    }
    else{
        var k = 60
        var l=60
    }
          pdf.addHTML($('#wholebracket'+i+'>#scoresheet'+n+'>div.brackdata>div.jQBracket.lr>div.bracket' ).get(0), 30, l+40, options, function() {

     exportIndex = parseInt(exportIndex) + 1;
     scoreIndex = parseInt(scoreIndex) + 1;
    var scoreLength = $('#wholebracket'+i+'>div.scoresheet').length;
    var holdLength = $('#wholebracket'+i+'>div.holding').length;
      if(exportIndex == exportLength) {
       pdf.setFontSize(10);
       pdf.setTextColor(39, 39, 206);
       pdf.setFontType("bold");
      pdf.text(splitTitle, 300, l-40,'center');
      pdf.setFontType("normal");
     pdf.setFontSize(18);
      pdf.setTextColor(39, 39, 206);
      pdf.text(300, l, "Scoresheet", 'center');                                                pdf.setFontSize(10);pdf.setFontType("normal");
    pdf.setTextColor(0, 0, 0);
     pdf.text(30, l+20,"Division: ");
    pdf.setFontType("bold");
     pdf.text(80, l+20,cname);
     pdf.setTextColor(150);                                                pdf.setFontType("normal");
    pdf.text(520, l+20,day);
    pdf.output('save', 'Bracketed_Scoresheet.pdf');                                             
    $('.demo').hide();                                                $('.score_table').hide();$(".demo").empty();
    $(".score_table").empty();document.getElementById('tournament').value='';
     return true;
     }     
    else {
     pdf.setFontSize(10);
     pdf.setTextColor(39, 39, 206);
      pdf.setFontType("bold");                                                pdf.text(splitTitle, 300, l-40,'center');                  
     pdf.setFontType("normal");
     pdf.setFontSize(18);
     pdf.setTextColor(39, 39, 206);
     pdf.text(300, l, "Scoresheet", 'center');
     pdf.setFontSize(10);
     pdf.setTextColor(0, 0, 0);
      pdf.text(30, l+20,"Division: ");
     pdf.setFontType("bold");
     pdf.text(80, l+20,cname);                                                pdf.setFontType("normal");
    pdf.setTextColor(150);
     pdf.text(520, l+20,day);
     pdf.addPage(); 
    if(scoreLength == n){

     n = 1; 
       i=i+1;
     } 
     else{
    n=n+1;i=i+0;
     }
     var k=0;                                                    recursivePDF(i,n,splitTitle);
     }
       return true;
     });
}
```

Inside .demo div we have n number of brackets in div#wholebracket which was incremented based on bracket length.We have recursivepdf function which was looped throughout to get all bracket data and finally if the loop reached, we have downloaded the pdf using pdf.save function.

In Safari, this code is working fine. But in Chrome and IE,PDF downloaded but getting only blank pages.

We also tried fromHTML instead of addHTML. But in that the jquery bracketing css is not applied. Just getting only list of names.

It would be helpful if anyone give some idea for this.

Thanks,
JeniDev.